# How to Change DataGrid ItemsSource Without Freezing the UI Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I have a list of Customers and I update my `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` to contain the customers list.
The problem is that after changing the `ItemsSource`, the thread update all binding targets to the values in each customer object, and this action freezes the UI for more than 30 seconds.
To solve this I tried to change the `ItemsSource` property in another `Thread` but the new thread can not access the datagrid control which owned by the UI thread.
If I put the `ItemsSource` changing code in `Invoke` methode the UI will freeze again.

```
//The following code is handled in another thread

// Geting a list of Customers
List<Customer> customers = manager.AllCustomers.SearchCustomers(fName, lName, address, city, tz, phone);

//Changing the DataGrid ItemsSource
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => customersSearchResultsDG.ItemsSource = customers);
//UI Thread is freezing until ItemsSource Changing complete
```

p.s
The amount of time it thinks not really bother me because I created a loading animation control.. but the freezing makes the animation stuck and that is what i'm trying to fix.

Comment: 30 seconds freeze because of assigning an already prepared collection seems crazy to me. Are you sure it's a problem of assignment and not e.g. retrieving data itself?

Comment: Each customer has 10 properties and the list has more than 20 customers... How much time should it take? I will debug it again and check if maybe there is another problem, but I'm not think so.

Answer (score 1):

When the UI thread in a WPF Application is busy, the UI will appear to freeze. There is nothing that can be done about that, but to avoid this situation, we typically do as much long running work as possible in background threads. However, as you have discovered, you cannot manipulate UI elements from a background thread, so there is only so much that we can do.

Other things that we can do to minimise the amount of time that the UI thread is busy is to use Virtualization, container recycling, [freezing resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or optimise used `Template`s. You can find out more about this from the [Optimizing Performance: Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

However, with the small number of items in your collection, it would seem to me that either you are loading and/or preparing your data extremely inefficiently, or you have incredibly large and complex `DataTemplate`s to define your items. The links provided above should help you if your problem is the latter.

Comment: I understand... But even if it takes only 10 second it will be a problem. Actually I don't really care if this action will take 5 minutes.. to solve to waiting feeling I created a loading control which works fine, but the "UI freezing", freezes the loading control too and the loading animation it stuck.

Comment: That is usual, but at least it confirms that the time taken is spent by the Framework rendering the UI, and not by data loading. To clarify, when the UI thread in a WPF is busy, *all controls in the UI* will appear to freeze.

Comment: so is there any solution for this problem or not?

Comment: When the UI thread is busy, the UI will freeze and nothing can be done about that.