# Splitting UI work to another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I'm currently working on an application that calls data from a WCF service and then loads that data into an ObservableCollection(`MyListOfBillsCollection`). From the OC, I set my datagrid's itemsource to that collection with the example below.

```
    ucLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    using (TruckServiceClient service = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        bills = await service.GetListOfBillsAsync();
        foreach (var item in bills)
        {
            billItem = MyListOfBillsCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id);
            if (billItem == null)
            {
                billItem = new ListOfBillsView();
                isNew = true;
            }

            billItem.Code = item.StockCode;
            billItem.Group = item.GroupName;
            ...

            if (isNew)
                MyListOfBillsCollection.Add(billItem);
        }
    }            
    dgFloor.ItemsSource = MyListOfBillsCollection; //Blocking UI Thread
    ucLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I've got an issue where, when I load that data from the OC and into my datagrid, my UI Thread gets blocked/application freezes and I need to show a 'spinner/loader' to the user that the application is loading the data.

Is it possible to load data into a datagrid and also showing-and-hiding my spinner with two diffirent UI threads? I know it must be possible, and I have done some research but I cannot get my head around it. So I'm posting my clean code(code without me trying to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`) here hoping that someone can give me some headers on what to do.

I have tried Async and Await and and used my code example in a `Task` method that returns a `Task` with all the code inside and I then used a dispatcher to release the UI work from within the method to the new Thread, but my 'spinners'  still will not work correctly and my window still freezes up. In the Task method, I removed the spinners and called the Show/Collapsed code from where I awaited the `Task` method.

Comment: How big is your 'MyListOfBillsCollection'?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @S.Akbari - I will have a look at that :)

Comment: @3615 - my collection can range from 250 - 500 items. It's not very big, but I still want to show the spinner for users with slower pc's.

Comment: @CareTaker22 well, it feels odd that thread blocks at that statement. It could be blocking at point where you call the service, or consume to much time during foreach(which is not the case for 500 items)... What control are you using for data display?

Comment: I'm using a DataGrid to display the items. The other thing is that I know it's the `dgFloor.ItemsSource = MyListOfBillsCollection;` that's freezing the aplpication, because when I load the data into the datagrid from another method that's not related to the WCF call, the application still freezes.

Comment: Also, I don't mind the 'loading' time that it takes to load the data from the WCF service as I can easily use await and async to load the data in the background. It's just that the same thing wont work when I try to load data into tha datagrid and also keep the spinners spinning with the same UI thread. ;(

Comment: @CareTaker22 take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27150111/5246145). Not that it solve your problem, but if you are blocking UI thread your spinner wouln't be running as well... But for such a small amount of data UI thread should not be blocked for noticeable period of time, unless there is some complex UI behind it.

Comment: I've had similar issue with a listbox in the past, the task is not freezing the ui, its probably the drawing of these records which does. try virtualization, so it only creates few at a time as you scroll

Comment: 3651 Thank you for posting that link and thank you adminSoftDK, you both helped me to understand that it's not the task that is blocking the UI but the drawing of the records and there is nothing I can do about it...or atleast I cannot use the spinners. The thing that helped a lot with the speed of the loading is to enable `EnableRowVirtualization="True"`. Thanks for that tip adminSoftDK! :)

Comment: Why do you assign observable collection to `ItemsSource` every time you got data? You should normally _bind_ `ItemsSource` to this collection from xaml, and clear this collection every time before adding new items.

Comment: I did bind the collection to my datagrid's itemsource in xaml. I bind to specific columns only. I'm only adding items from my WCF service that are new to the collection. So I don't need to clear it the collection every time. It removes the flickering effect that occurs everytime I clear the whole collection and add items again.